# Right alignment for table cell in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, datatable, pyqt

I have QStandardItemModel and QTableView. I want to have the number align to the right. How can i specify this in pyqt?

Now i have it like this (see ID) http://simple-database-explorer.googlecode.com/files/Main2.jpg

Working example:

```
self.model.setData(self.model.index(i, j, QtCore.QModelIndex()), value, role=0)
if isNumber(value):
    self.model.setData(self.model.index(i, j, QtCore.QModelIndex()), QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight), QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using QStandardItems as well?  Then you can use [setTextAlignment](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstandarditem.html#setTextAlignment).

#### Update

Using setData:

```
model.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight),
              QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
```

Comment: No, using setData. Will try it out

Comment: In that case, use setData(..., Qt.TextAlignmentRole).

Comment: could u pls provide a real example :) dont get the API

Comment: aha tnx. I was confused since i thought i should call setData only once. A working example is in my question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion then :)